# GridView Sorting CssClass not applying

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview with the following markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" Width="700px" skinid="gridview" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" AllowSorting="true" CssClass="gv">
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sort_asc" />
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sort_desc" />
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Project" DataField="Project" SortExpression="Project" />
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="Type" SortExpression="Type" />

</Columns>
</GridView>
```

However, my `SortedAscendingHeaderStyle` and `SortedDescendingHeaderStyle` `CssClass`'s are not being applied to the HTML when sorting.

My CSS is:

```
.gv .sort_asc
{
    display:block;
    padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
   background:url(/Admin/Images/Icons/arrow_down.jpg) no-repeat;  
}
.gv .sort_desc
{
    display:block;
    padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
   background:url(/Admin/Images/Icons/arrow_up.jpg) no-repeat;  
}
```

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Seems you want to set up/down arrow to clicked(sorted) column header! So, these way my code will work fine, just put the css to the specific column instead of all column, here I see header style handle these changes, so please try by changing to your specific column and let me know, thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand why its not just working anyway though? What is wrong with my code? We shouldn't have to do a workaround for this, as much as I appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Same code here but the class is not applying
I copied the code from this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2010/08/28/gridview-with-sort-arrows-and-showing-header-when-empty.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the way, the task can be accomplished:

## In .aspx file

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" SkinID="yourskinID"
   AllowSorting="True" onsorting="gvData_Sorting">
   <HeaderStyle CssClass="ascendingCssClass" /> <%-- put it into your SKIN file, 
       assume you're showing data in ascending initially  --%>
   <Columns>

   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

## In .cs file

```
private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";

public SortDirection GridViewSortDirection
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
            ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

        return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
    }
    set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
}

protected void gvData_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
    if (GridViewSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        //Put your CssClass here for descending
        gvData.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "descendingCssClass";
        SortGridView(sortExpression, DESCENDING);
    }
    else
    {
        GridViewSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
        //Put your CssClass here for ascending
        gvData.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "ascendingCssClass";
        SortGridView(sortExpression, ASCENDING);
    }
}

private void SortGridView(string sortExpression, string direction)
{
    DataTable dt = GetData();
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;
    gvData.DataSource = dv;
    gvData.DataBind();
}
```

### Update:

The sample/test css is a below: I just have used it test purpose, use your appropriate styling.

```
 tr.ascendingCssClass th a:link
 {
    color:Green;
    background-color:White;
 }    
 tr.ascendingCssClass th a:hover
 {
    color:Orange;
    background-color:White;
 }     
 tr.ascendingCssClass th a:visited
 {
     color:Black;
     background-color:White;
 }


 tr.descendingCssClass th a:link
 {
     color: red;
     background-color:Gray;
 }    
 tr.descendingCssClass th a:hover
 {
     color: Yellow;
     background-color:Gray;
 }     
 tr.descendingCssClass th  a:visited
 {
     color: Yellow;
     background-color:Gray;
 }
```

And, the `DataTable` function is as below:

```
DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("MyDataTable");
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(YourConnectionString))
    {
        //Your data retrival code goes here
        adapter.Fill(table); // Finally fill the datatable
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried this with no success. Furthermore I think you can override any styles in the Skin file by adding it to the markup (just like how I've specified a `Width`), so it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: In the `Header Section` where you click for ordering, there has `a` tag, you need to consider `a` and write appropriate `css` the `a` unless the tag `a` will get default css. Would you please try it again and update me accordingly, thanks for your time.

Comment: How can I access the `a` tag? This is automatically rendered from the GridView control I believe.

Comment: I'm editing and posting the ans again, please try with the latest version and also please let me know the update, thanks for your time.

Comment: Please let me know if the edited answer is working fine now, thanks for your time.

Comment: Hello @Curt, may I know that my suggested code is working fine, I've coded, tested and worked fine. So please let me know if you still have problem, thanks for your time.

Comment: My ascending/descending style needs to only be applied to the relevant item that is being sorted by. I believe this code simply changes the Header Style CssClass depending on which direction the content is sorted for.

Comment: @Curt, yes you're right, I assume you only wanted to change some css to the header section, so please let me know what would you like to change so that I can change my answer accordingly, thanks for your time.

Comment: I've added my CSS to the question, that should give you some direction, cheers. Do you have any idea why the built in `SortedAscendingHeaderStyle` is not working in my case?

Comment: `SortedAscendingHeaderStyle` should work according what you've done, however I've seen many program has face this kind of weird problem, however got a way as the way what I've said here, thanks for your time.